# Play my sound over the default notification sound when needed

Tags: android, audio, notifications

On onReceive method when i get a new message, after i do some checkups and see that the address number is the one i want. 
Is it possible to play my notification sound instead of the default message sound? And if a normal message comes then the default sound will play.
The thing is that the phone plays the sound first, and then my application, so there is a conflict there.
Ive searched for an answer but i couldnt find anything.

What i do is kind of unefficient. I play my sound 6 seconds after the default notifications plays like this:

```
private Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        getApplicationContext(), alarmSound);
                r.play();
            }
        };

        private void delayNotification() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            int millisDelay = 6000;
            handler.postDelayed(task, millisDelay);

        }
```

I know its not a good way to do it so thats y i came here:P

Answer (score 0):

```
  notification.sound =Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"
             +R.raw.tone);
```

Comment: Haven't checked this, but will that cancel/stop the default sound from playing?

Comment: this is how you can set your own sound instead of default.. share you code for further check

Comment: I don't even have code for it, I was just looking over  this and saw the answer for it. Was going to check on it when I got a chance, I didn't realize it overrode the default functionality. That is nice to know :)

Comment: Ive added my unefficient way:P

Comment: Sishin.. with this code, it will simply play this sound when my message comes and after that it will turn back to default?